# Select All Performance in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I'm current using DB2 and planning to use cassandra because as i know cassandra have a read performance greater than RDBMS.

May be this is a stupid question but I have experiment that compare read performance between DB2 and Cassandra.

Testing with 5 million records and same table schema.
With query `SELECT * FROM customer`. DB2 using 25-30s and Cassandra using 40-50s.

But query with where condition `SELECT * FROM customer WHERE cusId IN (100,200,300,400,500)` DB2 using **2-3s** and Cassandra using **3-5ms**.

Why Cassandra faster than DB2 with where condition? So i can't prove which database is greater with `SELECT * FROM customer` right?

FYI.

Cassandra: RF=3 and CL=1 with 3 nodes each node run on 3 computers (VM-Ubuntu)

DB2: Run on windows

Table schema:

```
cusId int PRIMARY KEY, cusName varchar
```

Comment: In Cassandra it would be more faster if you use execute async with separate query instead of in query. Check this https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the types of problems that Cassandra is good at solving, then the reasons behind *why* unbound ("Select All") queries suck become quite apparent.

Cassandra was designed to be a distributed data base.  In many Cassandra storage patterns, the number of nodes is greater than the replication factor (I.E., not all nodes contain all of the data).  Therefore, limiting the number of network hops becomes essential to modeling high-performing queries.  Cassandra performs very well with specific queries (which utilize the partition/clustering key structure), because it can quickly locate the node primarily responsible for the data.

Unbound queries (A.K.A. multi-key queries) incur the extra network time because a coordinator node is required.  So one node acts as the coordinator, queries all other nodes, collates data, and returns the result set.  Specifying a WHERE clause (with at least a partition key) and  while using a "Token Aware" load balancing policy, performs well for two reasons:

1. A coordinator node is not required.
2. The node primarily responsible for the range is queried, returning the result set in a single netowrk hop.

**tl;dr;**

Querying Cassandra with an unbound query, causes it to incur a lot of extra processing and network time that it normally wouldn't have to do, had the query been specified *with* a WHERE clause.

Comment: Thanks for your help! Now i'm little confuse about "A coordinator node is not required". So when a client connects to a node and issues a read or write request, that node serves as the coordinator https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/architecture/architectureClientRequestsAbout_c.html , or you mean for queries with where clause let the cassandra know which node contain data and returning the result set without talk to another node. Different from unbound queries that connects to a node (coordinator node) and this node need to talk to another node for data.

Comment: "queries with the where clause let Cassandra know which node contains the data" - Bingo. http://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/3.0/com/datastax/driver/core/policies/TokenAwarePolicy.html

Answer (score 2):

Even as a troublesome query like a no-condition range query, 40-50s is pretty extreme for C*. Is the coordinator hitting GCs with the coordination? Can you include code used for your test?

When you make a `select *` vs millions of records, it wont fetch them all at once, it will grab the fetchSize at a time. If your just iterating through this, the iterator will actually block even if you used executeAsync initially. This means that every 10k (default) records it will issue a new query that you will block on. The serialized nature of this will take time just from a network perspective. http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/3.1/manual/async/#async-paging explains how to do it in a non-blocking way. You can use this to to kick off the next page fetch while processing the current which would help.

Decreasing the limit or fetch size could also help, since the coordinator may walk token ranges (parallelism is possible here but its heuristic is not perfect) one at a time until it has read enough. If it has to walk too many nodes to respond it will be slow, this is why empty tables can be very slow to do a `select *` on, it may serially walk every replica set. With 256 vnodes this can be very bad.

Comment: I'm test the query with GUI tools. Toad for DB2 and DBeaver for Cassandra. Thanks for your help!